# Is there a way to remove Luddic Path Cells from my colonies?

Tags: starsector

I have to regularly destroy the supporting Ludic Path bases that I see in intel under *Colony threats*.

Can I cleanse my colonies entirely of them?

This is for Starsector 0.95.1a-RC6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that destroying the supporting Ludic Path bases will, in time, make cells on colonies "begin to fade out and disappear". [(source: wiki)](https://starsector.fandom.com/wiki/Colony_threats#Luddic_Path_Cells)

Another way would be to lower interest they have on your colony, by removing enough forbidden industries. I think you have to go below 7 interest for them to disappear, but I never tried it.